# MySQL - Select Top 5 with Rankings

Tags: mysql, ranking, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to get a users ranking getting his highest performances in every beatmap.

I get the user highest performance in every beatmap (only taking the top 5 performances) and adding them together, but it fails when the highest performance in one beatmap is repeated... because it counts twice

I'm based in this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129693/using-limit-within-group-by-to-get-n-results-per-group), but it doesn't works well for me...

Using MySQL 5.7

What i'm doing wrong?

[Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zseeqYmwdT62Vp3NZe5ss/7)

**Using this code:**

```
SET group_concat_max_len := 1000000;

SELECT @i:=@i+1 rank, x.userID, x.totalperformance FROM (SELECT r.userID, SUM(r.performance) as totalperformance 
FROM 
(SELECT Rankings.*
FROM   Rankings INNER JOIN (
  SELECT   userID, GROUP_CONCAT(performance ORDER BY performance DESC) grouped_performance
  FROM     Rankings
  GROUP BY userID) group_max
  ON Rankings.userID = group_max.userID
     AND FIND_IN_SET(performance, grouped_performance) <= 5

ORDER BY
  Rankings.userID, Rankings.performance DESC) as r
  GROUP BY userID) x
  JOIN 
     (SELECT @i:=0) vars
 ORDER BY x.totalperformance DESC
```

**Expected result:**

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| rank | userID | totalperformance |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 1    | 1      | 450              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 2    | 2      | 250              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 3    | 5      | 140              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 4    | 3      | 50               |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 5    | 75     | 10               | 
+------+--------+------------------+
| 6    | 45     | 0                | --
+------+--------+------------------+
| 7    | 70     | 0                | ----> This order is not relevant
+------+--------+------------------+
| 8    | 76     | 0                | --
+------+--------+------------------+
```

**Actual Result:**

```
+------+--------+------------------+
| rank | userID | totalperformance |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 1    | 1      | 520              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 2    | 2      | 350              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 3    | 5      | 220              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 4    | 3      | 100              |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 5    | 75     | 10               |
+------+--------+------------------+
| 6    | 45     | 0                | --
+------+--------+------------------+
| 7    | 70     | 0                | ----> This order is not relevant
+------+--------+------------------+
| 8    | 76     | 0                | --
+------+--------+------------------+
```

Comment: What version of mysql are you on?

Comment: Duplicates. If `grouped_performance` is `'10,9,8,7,6,6,5,...'` then FIND_IN_SET() will give 5 for both `6`, not 5 and 6. See https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=19ee91dc0ec0fd1f9928008af5c7135d - most inner subquery and its outer with additional column. The solution which you refer on needs the concatenated values to be unique.

Comment: Can you recheck with your expected output and data in fiddle. It is inconsistent, if you are picking only top 5 values for each user then the sum should be 250 for user id 2 instead of 350..

Comment: Thanks, im sorry, the fiddle are inconsistent, i eddited it with the correct one, let me check your answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have mentioned that you are picking only top 5 performances per user across `beatmaps` then you can try this way:

```
select @i:=@i+1, userid,performance from (
select userid,sum(performance) as performance from (
select 
  @row_number := CASE WHEN @last_category <> t1.userID THEN 1 ELSE @row_number + 1 END AS row_number,
  @last_category :=t1.userid,
t1.userid,
t1.beatmapid,
t1.performance

from (
select 
 userid, beatmapid,
 max(performance) as performance
from Rankings 
group by userid, beatmapid
) t1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @last_category := null) t2
ORDER BY t1.userID , t1.performance desc
) t3
where row_number<=5
group by userid
)
t4 join  (SELECT @i := 0 ) t5
order by performance desc
```

Above query will not consider duplicate Performance Score and pick only top 5 performance values.

[DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2zseeqYmwdT62Vp3NZe5ss/10)

Comment: Hi, i tested in my server and it fails in some exceptions... like only two duplicated performances in 1st place and no more performances, i updated the post and the fiddle with these exceptions

Comment: @ArturoRodriguez Edited the answer. In your expected output for user ID 3 should be 100 not 50

Comment: No, it's correct 50, the are two records with 50 in the same beatmap, we are taking only the highest one time

Comment: The answer is almost perfect, but the userID 3 has two records with 50 performance in the same beatmap so, it's a duplicate, and we only have to take one time

Comment: @ArturoRodriguez once again i have updated the answer. Hope this time you will get what you want.